# How to explain the difference between the following time series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, pattern-matching

I am conducting an empirical study for understanding the behavior of different people in a collaborative environment.

There are two types of events in my study: A and B.

Let's assume A means focusing on the work and B means talking to another person.

There are generally two kind of patterns that I observe:

1. A A A A B B A A A A B B A A A A B B A A ...
   (Focusing a little bit and discussing a little bit)
2. A A A A A A B A A A A A A A B A A ... (Focusing for a relatively long period of time and discussing for a short period of time)

How can I statistically explain the difference between these two time series of events?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by  a "mathematical" explanation of this?

Comment: There isn't really enough to see the pattern.  In the first one, it looks like $(A^4B^2)^\ast$.  In the second one, the number of $A$'s is changing.

Comment: As it stands, there isn't anything for anybody to say.  If you are generating these sequences according to some rule, you might want to share it.  Otherwise, we're just left guessing at your meaning.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I changed the explanation to make my question more clear!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have the reputation to just comment.

It looks like you want a rigorous way to write down two sequences.

Try converting A's to 0's and B's to 1's. Then the top sequence is a rational number and the second looks like it will be transcendental, but it's hard to tell without seeing more terms.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Campbell! I changed the explanation to make my question more clear

Answer (score 0):

The system won't let me comment because of my reputation.

Assuming the run length follows a Poisson distribution, you can get the average run length and conduct test on that